# Multiple desktops break in weird way when plugged into monitor

Tags: display, desktop, spaces

I have spent a lot of time searching for answers to this problem but I have not found anything.

I have an LG UltraFine 5K Display and a 2016 MacBook Pro running Catalina 10.15.7. The monitor is connected to the computer with a Thunderbolt 3 (USB‑C) cable. When I disconnect the computer, use it without the monitor, then connect it again, I often get the following bizarre behavior (also see `.gif` below):

1. The right-hand side of the menu bar disappears for all spaces/desktops except for one.
2. If I open an application it will only open in that one desktop.
3. I can interact with applications in other desktops, but if I try to resize or reposition them, they disappear and move to the one desktop.

I have tried the following things to fix the problem:

1. Wipe the hard drive and reinstall the operating system. This did not fix it.
2. Restart the computer. When I restart the computer with the monitor plugged in, it temporarily fixes the issue.
3. Unplug the monitor and plug it in again. This fixes the issue about half of the time. Sometimes I have to unplug the monitor and plug it back in four or five times before it works.

---

Below is a `.gif` of a recording of the issue. It is poor quality because Stack Exchange limits images to 2MB. But it should still be possible to see what's going on.

[image: Screen recording of the issue]

Edit: This issue occurs (but very rarely) when I unplug the computer from the monitor and use it as a laptop. In this case, the only way to fix it is to restart the computer or plug it back into the monitor.

Comment: Do you have this problem on different monitors?  Also, when you say "restarting temporarily fixes the problem," do you mean "temporarily until you disconnect and reconnect the monitor?"  Have you tried power cycling the monitor?

Comment: I have not tried on different monitors. Unfortunately I am unable to do so because I don't have more than one monitor.

Your interpretation is correct.

Power cycling the monitor produces the same result as unplugging the computer and plugging it back in.

Comment: "Produces the same results" meaning, it fixed it, it fixed it half the time, or it didn't fix it?  That said, to narrow this down to a monitor versus MacBook issue you've got to try it on a different monitor or if you know someone with another Mac have them test.  If the problem remains, it's the monitor and at least you have a direction to go in.

Comment: It fixed it half the time (until I unplug the computer again).

Comment: I would try powering down the monitor before disconnecting and making sure it's powered off before reconnecting.  See if that has any effect on things, but you still need to try and isolate it - Mac or monitor.

Comment: I don't understand how this could be a monitor issue. How could a monitor possibly cause the operating system to move a window from one desktop to another when I try to adjust the window's position on the page? In addition, if restarting the computer fixes the issue 100% of the time but restarting the monitor does not, doesn't that suggest it's a computer issue?

Comment: It's a Thunderbolt monitor which, unlike a regular monitor with DisplayPort and/or HDMI, handles a number of other things like PCIe, USB 3.x, etc. in addition to the DisplaySignal.  It's entirely possible the monitor "glitches" and it's not refreshing properly.  I know for a fact that Mac display kexts are very intolerant of signal anomalies; especially clock sync (not the time, but the display sync) issues.  That's why I was suggesting a specific order when connecting/disconnecting.  The power cycling "resets" the clock.  When you reboot, everything is in sync at that time.

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know that, and thanks for your help. I will see if I can find another monitor. But I am still skeptical that it could be a monitor issue. The behavior is so specific. I have also added an edit to the OP with some more information that I should have added originally but had forgotten about. The issue occurs once in a blue moon when I unplug the laptop from the monitor and use it without an external screen.

Comment: I can try power cycling, but it will be difficult to test since the issue does not occur all the time. The monitor has no power button (thanks Apple) so I would have to unplug it manually before connecting the computer each time.

Comment: It's just for diagnostics.  You're right that you shouldn't have to and there should be a power button as standby still draws (wastes) electricity when not in use.